# Trigger input file click in Ionic 4 after page change

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ionic-framework

I want to trigger/open a file input coming from another page in Ionic 4.

In page 1 I have a button to go to a modal, in page modal I want to automatically trigger the `<input file>` dialog

Component

```
ionViewWillEnter() {
    document.getElementById('file').click(); // Tried with this one 1st, this only works in Internet Explorer / Edge
    this.fileInput.nativeElement.click();    // And also this with @ViewChild
}
```

HTML

```
<input type="file" name="file" #file id="file" (change)="fileChange($event)" required>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it inserting a hidden input file in page1, when the user tries to go to page2 I trigger the file input.

When user finishes selecting the file I send the file event change to page 2 and manage all the logic in page 2.

Comment: But in question you asked that you want to trigger method in modal not in first page.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to open the file explorer just before seeing page 2/modal page.

Answer (score 3):

This is the code I'm using to trigger a click on an < input>-element:

```
@ViewChild("file") fileInput: ElementRef;

triggerClick() {
    let event = new MouseEvent('click', {bubbles: true});
    this.renderer.invokeElementMethod(this.fileInput.nativeElement, 'dispatchEvent', [event]);
}
```

Comment: Neither working nor error. Console log of event and fileInput
`MouseEvent {isTrusted: false, screenX: 0, screenY: 0, clientX: 0, clientY: 0, …}`
`<input id="file" name="file" required="" type="file">`

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
ionViewWillEnter() {
    document.getElementById('file').click(); // Tried with this one 1st
    this.fileInput.nativeElement.click();    // And also this with @ViewChild
}
```

To This:

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
    document.getElementById('file').click(); // Tried with this one 1st
}
```

Comment: Does not work, also tried with a setTimeout of 200ms
`console.log` of `document.getElementById('file')` `<input id="file" name="file" type="file">`

Answer (score 2):

> Try ngAfterViewInit() Lifecycle hook that is called after a
>   component's view has been fully initialized.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    document.getElementById('file').click();
}
```

Comment: This only works in Internet Explorer / Edge, not Chrome.
Also in Ionic this is the lifecycle `constructor --> ionViewDidLoad --> ionViewWillEnter --> ionViewDidEnter --> ionViewWillLeave --> ionViewDidLeave --> ionViewWillUnload`

Comment: @Chumillas It works on chrome as well as on android device. I checked it on both platform. You can [check here](https://ibb.co/cWyGP7). And ionic is built on angular so ionic support angular lifecycle hooks too.

Comment: Can you show me an example of opening an input file automatically without pressing any button? Just open the input file with navigation from pageA to pageB

Comment: You can [check here](https://ibb.co/jx83rn) input file opens automatically with navigation from one page to another. But I think there is a bug in chrome because first time when second page get loaded input file dialog does not get open, but on closing and reopening it works perfectly. This method work perfectly on [firefox](https://ibb.co/bzRTP7) and [Edge](https://ibb.co/iCmHHS).

Comment: It works in Edge but not in Chrome, I was searching a solution for Chrome that works in the first try. Also your solution provided is an already duplicated answer on this question.